# Can I narrow this down in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, narrowing, type-narrowing

I have a utility function to check whether a variable is not null or undefined, and I want TypeScript to narrow down the input variable if it passes the check, for example:

```
public init(input?: string): void {
    function isSpecified(input: any): boolean {
        return (typeof input !== "undefined") && (input !== null);
    }

    if (isSpecified(input)) {
        let copiedString: string = input; // <-- Error; input is still 'string | undefined'
    }
}
```

As you can see TS is not removing the possibility of the string being `undefined` even though the function makes that logically impossible.  Is there a way I can get this function call to narrow down `input` inside the `if` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a generic type guard function:

```
public init(input?: string): void {
    function isSpecified<T>(input: null | undefined | T): input is T {
        return (typeof input !== "undefined") && (input !== null);
    }

    if (isSpecified(input)) {
        let copiedString: string = input; // OK
    }
}
```

Note that if TypeScript narrows down a variable's union type through narrowing during an assignment, `isSpecified` will still not act as a type guard.  For example, in the following code, TS will give an error:

```
someMethod = () => {
    const foo: undefined | null | number = undefined;
    if (isSpecified(foo)) {
        this.nonNullValue = foo; // Error
    }
};
```

In the above, `foo` being assigned as `undefined` narrows the variable type and the `T` in `isSpecified` is `undefined`, so TS still doesn't treat `foo` as definitely being specified.  This can be worked around by using a type assertion (`val as ...`) to prevent narrowing:

```
someMethod = () => {
    //const foo = 123 as
    // ... or:
    const foo = undefined as
        undefined | null | number;
    if (isSpecified(foo)) {
        this.nonNullValue = foo;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've basically just written a typeguard function without adding the typeguard.

Change:

```
function isSpecified(input: any): boolean
```

to:

```
function isSpecified(input: any): input is string
```

More generally, you can use a generic version of the same thing, [as mentioned by Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935718/2088135):

```
function isSpecified<T>(input: null | undefined | T): input is T
```

Comment: But I don't want to say `is string`, it's more generic than that.  I want to say "it is not undefined or null".

Answer (score 0):

While the type guard function suggested in the other answers works well in many cases, in this case you have another much simpler option. Instead of checking for `(typeof input !== "undefined") && (input !== null)` just inline a check for `input != null`.

It's easy to forget that sometimes the type casting done by the double equal `==` and `!=` can actually be useful:

```
function init(input?: string): void {
    if (input != null) {
        let copiedString: string = input; // <-- input is now 'string'
    }
}
```

In javascript or typescript the following are all `true`:

```
undefined == null
null == null
'' != null
```